# How to change a value inside map within bigger map?

Tags: c++, string

I need to replace an inner value within a bigger map. For instance: "Bob" under key 1, to "Mike" under the same key 1. The question is inside the for loop. Please look at the code below:

```
using namespace std;

int main(void) {

map<string, map<string, string>> mm;
map<string, string> m;

string kk = "it_department";
string k = "0:1:2:3";
string v = "alice:bob:eve:trudy";


// separating keys and values with ":"

string k_sep = ":";
string v_sep = ":";

size_t k_pos = 0;
size_t v_pos = 0;

string k_tk;
string v_tk;

while((k_pos = k.find(k_sep))!=string::npos && (v_pos = 
    v.find(v_sep))!=string::npos) {
    k_tk = k.substr(0, k_pos);
    v_tk = v.substr(0, v_pos);
    m.insert(make_pair(k_tk,v_tk));
    k.erase(0, k_pos + k_sep.length());
    v.erase(0, v_pos + v_sep.length());
}
mm.insert(make_pair(kk, m));

map<string,string> :: const_iterator it;

for(map<string, map<string,string> >::const_iterator 
    ptr=mm.begin(); ptr!=mm.end(); ptr++) {
    it = ptr->second.find("1");
    printf("key: %s,v: %s\n", it->first, it->second);
    // at this moment, how can i replace value("bob") under "1" key to "mike" value???
}

return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please read the description of tags, the "c" tag has nothing to do here!

Comment: so where is your *question*? Edit, ok, I see it, in comment...

Comment: and please remove all redundant code, don't put parser in the Q, construct the map directly using literals. Generally speaking, post with [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to modify the map so don't  use a `const` iterator.

try this:

```
map<string,string> :: iterator it;

for(map<string, map<string,string> >::iterator ptr=mm.begin(); ptr!=mm.end(); ptr++) {
    it = ptr->second.find("1");
    if(it->second == "bob")
        it->second = "mike";
    cout<< it->first<< it->second<<endl;
}
```

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PF-q5A).